# Different result set for some reason when using df merging

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm fairly new to Python and very new to Pandas and I'm trying to analyze data in two CSV files. I'm taking a subset of records in File1 and looking for ones that are not in File2. I'm reading the files into a data frame, creating another data frame that is stripped down to just the 2 or 3 key columns I care about and using a merge to compare the results.

The files are identical in structure and headings. There's about 40 or 50 columns total. The composite key I care about is the combination of "IDnum" and "Status" and everything outside of that is just context so I've joined the files on those columns.

What's bizarre is that I'm getting incorrect results when I read in the complete file, but if I manually delete all the unnecessary columns, I get the correct result. I'm not sure why this is even a factor because I'm not changing the rows and I'm not changing the join on attributes.

```
File1= pd.read_csv('PersonList1.csv', encoding='ANSI', index_col=False)  # Read Source file into data frame
File2 = pd.read_csv('PersonList2.csv', encoding='ANSI', index_col=False)  # Read Target CSV file in data frame

# Reduce number of columns
keep_col = ['ID_num', 'Status']
File1_keep_col = File1[keep_col]

# Filter down to the subset I want in File 1
File1ActivesBoolean = File1_keep_col['Status'] == 'A'  # Returns boolean results
File1Actives = File1_keep_col[File1ActivesBoolean] 

# Execute merge of File1  subset and get results
CompareJoin = pd.merge(File1Actives, File2,
                                         on=['ID_num', 'Status'],
                                         how='left',
                                         indicator=True)
CompareBoolean = CompareJoin['_merge'] == 'left_only'
CompareResult = CompareJoin[CompareBoolean]
```

When I take the full file I incorrectly get 61926 records in File1 that are not in File2. When I delete all columns from File 2 leaving just "ID_num" and "Status" columns I get the 627 (which is correct). I know the numbers don't mean much without seeing the data, but it is orders of magnitude off so I'm certain I'm not accounting for something in this join, but can't figure out what. Would greatly appreciate any help from the pros out there.

Comment: Do you have duplicate keys in your 2nd df?

Comment: @Datanovice - Not in the subset I'm searching for, but your question led to a resolution. To check, I limited File2 to rows where Status == A manually via Excel. The subsequent file generated a "You are trying to merge on object and int64 columns".  Figured it was excel formatting and to solve that problem I used "File2['ID_num']=File2['ID_num'].astype(str). Converting that data type has it working consistently. I never got that error using the original file. So I've got the answer but would love to hear any insight on the root cause if anyone has it.

Comment: Usually when I get more keys in my left column after merging it's usually due to duplicates in the right, so naturally it has to create more rows. If the dtypes aren't the same then it usually throws an error. Glad you came to a conclusion. Keep up the learning!